# Make datalist required

Tags: php, html, html-datalist

I would like the user not to be able to submit a form unless they have selected something from the dropdown `datalist` which appears as they type. If they just typed something random, I **don't** want the form to be submitted.

If this isn't possible, would a better option to be to check if the typed text appears in the datalist when the user submits?

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" list="browsers">
    <datalist id="browsers">
        <option value="Internet Explorer">
        <option value="Firefox">
        <option value="Chrome">
        <option value="Opera">
        <option value="Safari">
    </datalist>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']
   // function to check if something from the datalist was clicked and NOT just typed
}else{
   echo'Select something from the datalist!';
}
```

While I can set the `datalist` as required, this can easily be by-passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to go with server side validation,

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" list="browsers" name="items" required>
    <datalist id="browsers" >
        <option value="Internet Explorer">
        <option value="Firefox">
        <option value="Chrome">
        <option value="Opera">
        <option value="Safari">
    </datalist>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']
   $check = array('Internet Explorer', 'Firefox', 'Chrome', 'Opera', 'Safari');

if(in_array($_POST['items'], $check)){
  // Code to be execute. 
} else{
   echo'Select something from the datalist!';
}

}else{
   echo'Select something from the datalist!';
}
```

Comment: If datalist is dynamic, where the data is coming from? If the data is coming from API, and  API call is happening from PHP, you have your dynamic $check array already available.

Answer (score 1):

Using `required` in the **input** tag that has the same id as the datalist you are targeting will check force the user to input something.

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" list="browsers" required>
    <datalist id="browsers">
        <option value="Internet Explorer">
        <option value="Firefox">
        <option value="Chrome">
        <option value="Opera">
        <option value="Safari">
    </datalist>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']
   // function to check if something from the datalist was clicked and NOT just typed
}else{
   echo'Select something from the datalist!';
}
```

However it will not block the user from giving an input that is not listed in the dropdown. That needs to be checked via Javascript just before submission.

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return myCheckFunction(this)>

  <!-- Your form items -->
  <!--------------------->

</form>

<script>
  myCheckFunction(form) {
    // get the values that are currently under the datalist tag in option tags
    // get the user input
    // compare the options with the user input
    // if one is equal with the user input submit the form with the method submit();
    // else don't submit the form, the user will have to change his input
  }
</script>
```

If you wish some help with the js i'll be happy to help.

Comment: You have also got to perform server-side validation. Client-side validation is easily bypassed.

Comment: Is JavaScript the only option? I was really hoping not to have to use it.

Comment: I don't have any other idea : with JavaScript it could be really easy actually. On submit you run a function to check if input == one of the option value. If so submit can proceed, else the submission doesn't take place. I can help you with the js if you would like.

Comment: Thing is though, JavaScript is also done on the client-side

Comment: Whether the options are dynamic or not doesn't make any difference, the check will take place just before submission on client side.